# Windows ServiceBus 1.1 - how to change default ports

Tags: windows, wcf, servicebus

is there a way to change the default ports of
Windows ServiceBus 1.1 for
"Internal Communication Port Range 9000 - 9004" ?

Is it recommended to do so?

We have a conflicting application needing 9004, where
we cannot change the default port.
Thus we would like to change the ServiceBus port.

Thanks,
Karl

Answer (score 0):

In the tool 'Service Bus Configuration' you can enter these settings only with the option 'Create a New Farm' >> 'With Custom Settings'. 
At the bottom there is a field 'Internal Communication Port Range' starting at 9000.

It doesn't seem to be possible for the creation of a ServiceBusNamespace, only for the creation of a farm.

If you want to do it with the 'Service Bus PowerShell', have a look at the command 'New-SBFarm' here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248757%28v=azure.10%29.aspx.

Keyword:  -InternalPortRangeStart 9000